# Can I set a grid's element to an area of another grid?

Tags: html, css, sass, css-grid

I have a main CSS grid which contains two other grids (1 and 2) in two **different blocks**.
Every grids define their own areas, and every "grid-items" are set in their respective area (example : `grid-area: top1;`).

Here's a html example :

```css
.main-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas:
    "left"
    "right";

  @media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
    grid-template-columns: 100px 50px;
    grid-template-areas:
      "left right";
  }
}

.grid-1 {
  grid-area: left;
}

.inner {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}

.grid-1 .inner {
  grid-template-areas:
    "top1"
    "bottom1";
}

.grid-2 {
  grid-area: right;
}

.grid-2 .inner {
  grid-template-areas:
    "top2"
    "middle2"
    "bottom2";
}


.item-a, .item-b, .item-c, .item-d, .item-e {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.item-a {
  grid-area: top1;

  @media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
    height: 50px;
  }
}
.item-b {
  grid-area: top2;

  @media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
    height: 50px;
    grid-area: bottom1;
  }
}
.item-c {
  grid-area: bottom1;

  @media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
    grid-area: top2;
  }
}
.item-d {
  grid-area: middle2;
}
.item-e {
  grid-area: bottom2;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-grid">
  <div class="grid-1">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="item-a">A</div>
      <div class="item-b">B</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-2">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="item-c">C</div>
      <div class="item-d">D</div>
      <div class="item-e">E</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to know if it's possible to set `.item-a` to an area of `.grid-2` ?

For some reason media queries don't work here, so I created a [**Codepen snippet in scss**](https://codepen.io/julian-printemps/pen/OgQEBw)

Comment: Do you want to use `position: absolute`?

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to do.

But here's one thing to note:

You have `grid-template-columns`, `grid-template-rows` and `grid-template-areas` applied to the `.inner` elements.

```
.grid-1 .inner {
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas: "top1" "bottom1";
}

.grid-2 .inner {
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas: "top2" "middle2" "bottom2";
}
```

These are grid container properties. They will have no effect unless the element also has `display: grid` or `display: inline-grid`. In your code, the `.inner` elements are `display: block` (default).

Because `.inner` is not a grid container, the grid properties assigned to its child elements – `.item-a` through `.item-e` – are having no effect.

Just remember that the scope of a [***grid formatting context***](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-concepts) is the parent-child relationship. Elements that are not children of a grid container are not grid items and will ignore grid properties. Therefore, you will always have to use `display: grid` or `display: inline-grid` if you want to apply grid container properties to the parent and grid item properties to the child.

Comment: I forgot to add `display: grid;` on the inner class indeed. What I'm trying to do is change the order to ACDBE for small devices. But as you mentioned, the context being parent/child relationship I guess this is not possible. AB are in one context, CDE in another.